# What is the rationale for only allowing two site collection administrator users?

Tags: 2010

What is the rationale for only allowing two site collection administrator users? I would like to understand why this design decision was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many Site Collection Administrators as you want by adding them in Site Settings.  The idea behind specifying two during site collection creation is simply to have you think about who should be the backup in case the first SCA is out (medical, vacation, in an RV, under an RV, whatever)